# Логическая задача с игральными кубиками

Tags: логика

На столе поставили башню из игральных кубиков (костей). Игральный кубик содержит на своих гранях числа от одного до шести.
Посчитали сумму чисел на всех видимых гранях кубиков, из которых состоит башня. Получилось S1.
Сняли верхний кубик с башни и опять посчитали сумму чисел на всех видимых гранях кубиков - получилось S2.
И оказалось, что S1 - S2 = 19.
После того, как сняли верхний кубик с башни, какое число стало видно на верхней грани **получившегося верхнего кубика** башни?

Comment: Единица, знамо дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

каждый кубик содержит сумму 21

пусть будет башня в N кубиков, тогда сумма всех граней будет:

```
A + (21 - X2 - Y2) + (21 - X1)
```

где

`A` - сумма видимых граней всех кубиков кроме верхних двух

`X2`, `Y2` - невидимые грани второго сверху кубика (т.е. грани которые находятся сверху и снизу)

`X1` - невидимая грань первого сверху кубика (т.е. грань которая находится снизу)

когда сняли верхний кубик, то сумма видимых граней стала:

```
A + (21 - Y2)
```

значит

```
A + (21 - X2 - Y2) + (21 - X1) - (A + (21 - X2)) = 21 - X1 - X2 = 19
```

откуда

```
X1 + X2 = 2
```

значит всего возможно вариантов:

```
(1, 1)
```

т.е. на верхней грани видна `1`